# Cron not running python script on Ubuntu AWS

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a simple script that should print test in the shell, just to see if cron is working. I have tried a lot but unfortunately I am not able to run it (it works fine from the shell using the following command "/usr/bin/python3 ~/Cloudtest/main.py").
The following is the content of my crontab file (Written using crontab -e):

" * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 ~/Cloudtest/main.py "

I am expecting to see test printed in the shell every minute,  but nothing is happening. Any ideas please?

If it makes any difference, I am using ubuntu on AWS.

Thanks!

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't see the output of cron script in your shell as logged in user.

To verify whether the this job got executed successfully or not, check the `/var/log/cron` file, you shound see something like this.

```
$ tail /var/log/cron
Oct  8 22:00:00 dev-db crond[18340]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /home/root/bin/system_check &)
Oct  8 23:00:00 dev-db crond[20348]: (oracle) CMD (/bin/sh /home/oracle/bin/cleanup.sh &)
Oct  8 23:59:00 dev-db crond[20399]: (john) CMD (/bin/sh /home/john/bin/backup.sh &)
```

This will allow you to see if the job got executed or not.

If instead you want to see the actual outputs, you should redrive the output to a file.

```sh
$ crontab -e
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 ~/Cloudtest/main.py > /home/john/logs/backup.log 2>&1
```

**Replace `john` with your user**